# How to load a data in mysql faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

How can i enhance the speed of querying in mysql table using PHP?

Because as of now I have 152000 records and every time I load this my page won't open. Just a white screen. I also added some indexes but it doesn't enhance my table query.
Here's my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
`itemid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`itemcode` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin',
`itemname` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`itemdesc` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`itembrand` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`itemunit` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`salescatid` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`salescatname` VARCHAR(128) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`entrydate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemid`),
INDEX `itemcode` (`itemcode`),
INDEX `itemname` (`itemname`),
INDEX `itemdesc` (`itemdesc`),
INDEX `itembrand` (`itembrand`),
INDEX `itemunit` (`itemunit`),
INDEX `salescatid` (`salescatid`),
INDEX `salescatname` (`salescatname`),
INDEX `entrydate` (`entrydate`)
)

COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=157329;
```

Sample query that load slowly

```
SELECT itemid,itemcode,itemname FROM items ORDER BY itemid DESC
```

Comment: Add to your question a typical query you are trying to run

Comment: Please show us the code that you have profiled as being problematic. And did you turn on error reporting?

Comment: ok I updated my question. I have error reporting but my browser won't tell me the error. Just a blank page. But if i reduced my data it will open.

Comment: That query should not be slow, it's a simple select on an indexed primary key. Are you sure it's the database portion of the page that is slow and not the script? A blank screen in this case is probably PHP running out of memory, since you appear to be loading the entire table into memory. Fix/check your error logs.

Comment: Ok if it is PHP issue how can i do that? How can I increase the size of my memory in PHP?

Comment: First, I'd make sure that is the problem. Fix your error reporting and check the logs. You can increase PHPs memory limit, but unless it is very low, that's probably not the best solution. Loading 150k rows is probably not needed, can you aggregate or paginate, or search or filter, or something to reduce the number needed at once?

Comment: The reason why i need to load the data is I am creating an add form and there is a portion of select box and it contains all of my items in the table.

Comment: I'd suggest you investigate some method to allow that field to be populated via a search or something, possibly using an AJAX autocomplete type system. If you intend to put 150k options in a select box, all I can say is good luck :) I'm not even sure how well a browser would handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White screen means either error in PHP or timeout (HTTP code 500, check the logs).

Timeout is more likely to appear because copying 150k rows through the network and sending to browser takes long, not selecting from DB.

You also might run into memory issues.

**Pagination is a good approach I can imagine to help you.**

In most common PHP versions, error reporting is off by default.

Put these lines on top of your script to enable it:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

To get your PHP settings, use `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Going through the comments you need to reduce the data sent to the browser (like Brenton Alker mentioned).

Besides pagination, you can use *lazy loading* techniques (see this [Lazy loading SELECT element options w/ jquerymobile, c# and asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185112/lazy-loading-select-element-options-w-jquerymobile-c-sharp-and-asp-net)) and filtering via ajax to load smaller portions or use *typeahead* instead of select boxes.

Imagine it to be very hard to find options in such a big select/dropdown box. Try other form elements and ways to get to select an option.